# Different cooldown length for different parts of a command

Tags: discord.js, rate-limiting

I have a command called "work". This command has 3 parts, list, apply and regular work. When user runs -work list, available jobs are being listed, I don't want any cooldown for this part. -work apply changes the job of the user, and -work just generates random number. So, I want it like when user runs -work apply and change their job, a 1-day cooldown must be applied. And when user just passes -work I want a 1-hour cooldown. I thought of something like different parts of the command would return different strings, such as work_apply and work_work, and use that information to apply different cooldown lengths. But that isn't possible since I can't apply any cooldown without having the output from the command, and to have some output I must run the command. So I can't apply any cooldown without running it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really know how your command handler works so i will give you an idea.

you can try making a map and pushing the message author and the time they ran the command. once you done this, the next time the same person runs the code under the time limit, set it so that the command handler looks for the member in the map and if they find it, they check when they last ran the command and if its under the time limit, it returns the function

again i dont know how your command handler works but here is how i did it

PS. If your entire command is in 1 file then the code im gonna show wont work. you should try to edit some parts of the code to make it work to ur liking

```js
// command handler file

const cooldowns = new Map();

let name = command.name;

if (!cooldowns.has(name)) {

    cooldowns.set(name, new Discord.Collection());

}

if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('ROLE_ID')) { // role that bypass cooldown
    
    const current_time = Date.now();
    const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(name);
    const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;
    
    if (time_stamps.has(message.author.id)) {
    
        const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;
    
        if (current_time < expiration_time) {

            message.reply({

                content: `Please wait until the cooldown has ended`

            });

            return;

        }

    }

    time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
    setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);

}



// command file

module.exports = {

    name: 'commandname',
    cooldown: 15 // this has to be in seconds | you can type '0' if there r no cooldowns

    async execute(YOUR PARAMETERS) {

        // command code

    }

}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to say is different cooldown length for different parts of 1 single command. This seems to make whole command in 1 certain cooldown. This is not helpful. Thanks.